# Host complete WordPress website in Amazon CloudFront or any other CDN

Tags: wordpress, caching, cdn, amazon-cloudfront, w3-total-cache

### What I would like to do

According to a Amazon Senior Architect to whom I spoke recently, it is possible to **cache dynamic website content in Amazon CloudFront**.

The way I understand how this could work, is that in addition to doing a page cache of each page which has been accessed, cache the page in CloudFront too.

### What I have tried

I have experimented a lot with W3 Total Cache and its settings but did not find a solution to this problem. I also have tried to set up CloudFront directly in the AWS control panel but did not find a way to cache the **static** result (html?) of WordPress's **php** calls.

### Question

How would you tackle the issue?
How can I cache a static version of WordPress's dynamic pages in CloudFront or any other CDN?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

most CDNs advertise that they can cache dynamic web sites. Unless they have very specific information about the pages they need to serve, they can't. There are situations where the "penalty" of a CDN for a dynamic page isn't that bad, but having an additional hop in-between the web server and the end user can only be faster in some very specific situations. The main reason is the absense of a Last-Modified header for the generated pages.

From my experience working with (at) CDN providers, the most performant way to include a CDN is to use a different hostname for the static assets and point that hostname to the CDN with your web server as the origin server.

Jan

Comment: Hi Jan, thank you for your answer! The main reasons why I am looking at CDNs to cache dynamic WordPress content is twofold: 1) In order to mitigate DDoS attacks, a large CDN provider recommended to cache basically the whole website in a CDN (with the dynamic content being the tricky part) and 2) Many web hosts have better pricing for CDN cached bandwidth than for "classic" bandwidth delivered through the web server. Do you have any advice to cache a whole WordPress site in a CDN (e.g. AWS CloudFront)?

Comment: one road I would go down for my own research would be something like cache plugins for Wordpress. For example: https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-super-cache/ I don't have any experience with this specific one, but it should allow you to make your wordpress site "static enough" to be served via a CDN. The plugin has (or should have, from an architectural point of view) the internal intelligence to understand if a request should be served dynamically (user logged in) or statically (any anonymous user reading a blog). I would consider that a possibel way forward in your case...

Comment: I will definitely look into WP Super Cache which seems to create static html pages. Thank you for pointing me to this plugin. I was looking into W3 Total Cache before but it does not seem to create static html pages.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a concept plugin which aims to do this:

https://github.com/PeterBooker/wp-cloudfront-helper